# VBA filter out dates less than 30

Tags: excel, vba, filter

Does anyone know a vba code that filters all data older than 30 day in excel?  Meaning it will show the items that are older than 30 days. Pretty standard data set. Column of names, times, and dates recorded. I just want to open the workbook and filter out anyone less than 30 days old. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A normal data filter will filter it out.

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")

With sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<" & CLng(Date - 30)
End With
```

Comment: Thank you @Michael Rosa